# Need an example/counterexample of continuous and increasing function.

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, examples-counterexamples

If $\mu$ is a finite measure on the measurable space $\big( X, \mathscr{F} \big)$, $f : X\to [ 0, +\infty)$ is measurable.

Then $\textbf{does it exist a continuous function $g : [ 0, +\infty)\to [ 0, +\infty) $ such that $g(x)$ increases to $+\infty$}$  as $x\to +\infty$ and
$$\int_X g\big( f(x) \big) \, \mu (dx) < +\infty \,\, ? $$

W.l.g. we may assume $\mu(X) = 1$. Since 
$$\int_X g\big( f(x) \big) \, \mu (dx)= \int_0^\infty g(y) \, \nu(dy) $$
where $\nu(B) = \mu\circ f^{-1}(B)$ for $B$ Borel subset of $[0, +\infty)$,
then it is equivalent to ask that given a nonnegative random variable $Y$, does it exist a continuous function $g : [ 0, +\infty)\to [ 0, +\infty) $ such that $g(x)$ increases to $+\infty$  as $x\to +\infty$ and $g(Y)$ is of finite expectation ?

---

If $\mu(X) = +\infty$, it is easy to come up with a counterexample :

Pick $f(x) = x$ defined on $\big( \mathbb{R}_+, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}_+) , dx \big)$ and  there is no continuous increasing function $g : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x) = +\infty$ and $g\circ f$ is integrable.

Since $\lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x) = +\infty$, for large $M > 0$, $g(x) > 1$ as $x\geq M$, then
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx  = \int_0^M g(x) \, dx + \int_M^\infty g(x) \, dx 
\end{align*}
note that the first integral is finite, while the second is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do the second version. This is easy if $\nu$ has compact support, so suppose this is not the case.

Then we can fix a sequence $0=x_0 < x_1 < \ldots$, $x_n\to\infty$, so that with $I_n=[x_{n-1}, x_n)$, we have that $\mu(I_n)\le (1/2)\mu (I_{n-1})$: just choose the next $x_n$ so that the current interval contains at least $2/3$ of the remaining measure. So $\mu(I_n)\le 2^{-n}$, and we can now define an integrable $h$ by $h=2^{n/2}$ on $I_n$. Make this continuous and strictly increasing to obtain $g$, with $g\le h$.